# Mysql sting to select everything there column only has 1 out of 2 outcomes

Tags: mysql

have a database that has 2 columns I want to select from `Name` (I know this needs changing) and Matched.

I would like to run a query that selects the results where Name has the Status "Matched" but does not have the Stats "settled"

From the example below the top row on has Matched so I would like to see it but the Armininia below has both Matched and Settled so I don't want to return it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.name, t1.status
FROM table t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (select 1 from table t2 where t2.name=t1.name and t2.status="SETTLED")
 and t1.status="MATCHED"
```

Above is: "*I would like to run a query that selects the results where Name has the Status "Matched" but does not have the Stats "settled"*"

Answer (score 0):

Group by name and set the conditions in the having clause:

```
select name
from tablename
group by name
having sum(name = 'MATCHED') > 0 and sum(name = 'SETTLED') = 0
```